# JsonSubTypes does not wraps while serializing

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

I'm trying to make a rest API where you can control the size of an image using different modes (Size constraints, adapt, extend, coerce or resize), each mode having different parameters. Here is my class diagram :

[image: diagram]

Here is my `BaseSizeConstraint`:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
        use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
        include = JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT
)
@JsonSubTypes({
        @Type(value = CoerceConstraint.class, name = "coerce"),
        @Type(value = ExtendConstraint.class, name = "extend"),
        @Type(value = AdaptConstraint.class, name = "adapt"),
        @Type(value = ResizeConstraint.class, name = "resize")
})
public abstract class BaseSizeConstraint implements ISizeConstraint {
}
```

When I try to add new image descriptor to a template using the API with this body :

```
{
    "name": "ImgResize",
    "missingImageBehavior": "Fail",
    "sizeConstraint": {
        "resize": {"height": 50, "width": 50 }
    }
}
```

It works, but the response I get is different :

```
{
    "name": "ImgResize",
    "alias": null,
    "sizeConstraint": {
        "width": 50,
        "height": 50
    },
    "missingImageBehavior": "Fail"
}
```

As you can see the sizeConstraint is no more wrapped, giving no indication about the type of the constraint...

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my ImageDescriptor's sizeConstraint getter was typed as `ISizeContraint` instead of `BaseSizeConstraint` (which held the subtypes)